# Can I delete files on form close?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i have a basic program that copies a file to a temp directory , extracts the file and then opens the file. What i want to do is then delete the file from the directory on app close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a function that handles the FormClosing event and put the code in there to delete the file.

```
Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
```

Comment: @BSanders Just be careful, this event will only be fired if they close using the X button, or via a button you provide. If they use task manager, or their computer crashes etc, the temp directory won't be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to remove all my scan logs after I close my app vb studio

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim s As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

    Dim c As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(s & "/jrt.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(s & "/jrt.txt")
    End If

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(s & "/Rkill.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(s & "/Rkill.txt")
    End If

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(c & "/Documents/cc*.reg") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(c & "/Documents/cc*.reg")
    End If

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("c:/AdwCleaner") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:/AdwCleaner", FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
    End If
End Sub
```